# How to Make the Bricks Shake Like an Earthquake Simulation

Tags: animation, graph-editor

My next task to do with these bricks is that I need to get them to animate like there is an earthquake making them shake.

Here's what I got so far. I got two sides of bricks on each side and I want to animate them like an earthquake.

I got an image here for an example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your result may look like.

[image]

---

Go to the Graph-Editor. Set a (location) keyframe for your cube, then select the "Z Location".

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the side panel, and select modifiers.

Add a noise modifier and controll your Earthquake with Scale, Strength, Start, etc.

[image]